# Launch vscode task in external terminal via tasks 2.0.0

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to launch bat file via external terminal, not inside a vscode terminal?

Task sample:

```
{
    "label": "Build",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "./build.bat",
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
    },
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tasks.json version 2.0.0 edit:**

```
{
    "label": "%name%",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "Start-Process -FilePath \"%path to bat%\"",
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "never"
    },
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    }
},
```

---

For older tasks.json version:
So, while vscode uses PowerShell as main environment on windows, next piece worked for me:

```
"command": "Start-Process -FilePath \"path to script\"",
"presentation": {
    "reveal": "never"
},
```

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on what makes your process open in an external terminal. Thanks :) It seem your answer will not work on other operating systems than windows

Comment: @538ROMEO That is right, answer is based on powershell which is exclusive to windows environment

Comment: Hmm, it didn't seem to work when trying to execute an EXE file. It just opens the integrated terminal instead of a new window

Answer (score 0):

I used the above answer with a few changes to run a task where I wanted to open cmd and after run a command, in my case, I wanted to run `iex -S mix phx.server` to run my Phoenix app inside IEx (Interactive Elixir).

So here's what I did, in the **tasks.json**:

```
{
  "label": "task name",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "Start-Process",
  "args": [
    "-FilePath",
    "C:/WINDOWS/System32/cmd.exe",
    "-ArgumentList",
    "/K iex -S mix phx.server"
  ],
  "options": {
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "requireFiles": [],
  },
  "presentation": {
    "reveal": "never"
  },
},
```

I just put in the `command` property the "Start-Process" and all the remaining things I added as `args`. The command you want to execute after opening the external terminal must go into the `-ArgumentList` parameter